# Count results from for loop in R

Tags: r

I have a for loop that takes a sample size of n=10 over a uniform distribution U(0,5) that finds the difference between the max value and theta. Right now, it's printing out the numbers that are less than 0.05 but I am interested in the number of times that occurs instead but I don't know how to do that. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
for (i in 1:100) {
  theta <-5
  x<-runif(10,0,5)
  Tn<-max(x)
  a <- abs(Tn - theta)
  if(a<0.05){
    print(a)
  }
}
```

This would output

```
[1] 0.03909178
[1] 0.0484645
[1] 0.04538883
[1] 0.04585505
[1] 0.0257083
[1] 0.01073834
[1] 0.02926414
[1] 0.01092849
[1] 0.004529301
[1] 0.04686977
```

But I would like it to output 10

Comment: Just create `count <- 0` outside the loop, and increment `count <- count + 1` within the `if` and `print(count)`

Comment: You make condition to show number that is < .05. If you want to count the number. Just make counter outside the loop. Increment in if condition. Print out at the end.

Answer (score 0):

You could also do this. Save results in a vector and then use indexing:

```
#Vector for results
vres <- c()
#Loop
for (i in 1:100) {
  theta <-5
  x<-runif(10,0,5)
  Tn<-max(x)
  a <- abs(Tn - theta)
  vres[i] <- a
}
#Count
length(vres[vres<0.05])
```

Answer (score 0):

This would be the R approach. Rather than running a loop, the replicate function does the same operation n number of times;

```
theta=5
set.seed(123) # Done to allow reproducible results from simulations

sum( replicate (n=100, { abs( max( runif(10,0,5) ) -theta) < 0.05} )  )
#[1] 10
```

All the functions inside the curley-braces are "vectorized" so they can be passed through each other. You read the expression from the inside out, so the 'runif' call is first, followed by 'max', followed by the logical tests. In R you can `sum` up a logical vector to see how may are TRUE.